# Possible to always update to latest PPA package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using a Linux kernel from a PPA on Ubuntu Server.

Ideally should the PPA kernel have a higher version number, but I don't trust it.

**Question**

Is it possible to have the kernel excluded from being updated when doing `apt-get upgrade`?

Or even better: never overwrite the PPA kernel with an Ubuntu kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent any package from getting upgraded using the following command:

```
$ echo "package-name hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

You can include the package again in the upgrade list using:

```
$ echo "package-name install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To check the status, you can use

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep package-name
```